# UV curable adhesive

Tags: solubility, polymers

I'm looking for a UV curable adhesive that can be removed without peeling or burning.  Ideal removal would be some kind of solvent over a relatively short period of time. I also need it to have a viscosity of 50,000 - 70,000 cP.

Right now I'm using [this](http://www.dymax.com/adhesives/products/724) but it's not ideal.  Someone has to be there to remove it.  I'm doing this with a robot and robot's aren't very good at removing it.

Anyone out there have any ideas?

**Edit**

I've been looking at UV curable investment casting wax.  I think that this could be melted off.  The only problem with what I have found is the viscosity.  They are made for 3D printing and have a relatively low viscosity.

Comment: Dentists use UV cured adhesives all the time. Try looking up bite block and what it's made of.